# GridView (+BaseAdapter) calls ofen position 0 in touch mode

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

Hello I've got a problem with my BaseAdapter which I use to fill a GridView.
It calls on each scroll pretty often the position 0. Here is the LogCat:

```
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 1
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 2
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 3
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 4
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 5
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 6
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 7
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 8
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 9
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 10
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 11
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 12
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 13
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 14
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 15
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 16
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 17
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 18
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 19
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 20
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 21
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 22
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 23
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 24
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 25
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 26
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 27
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 28
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 29
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 30
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 31
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 32
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 33
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 34
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 35
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 36
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 37
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 38
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 39
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 40
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 41
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 42
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 43
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 44
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 45
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 46
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 47
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 48
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 49
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 50
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 51
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 52
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 53
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 54
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 55
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 56
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 57
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 58
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 59
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 60
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 61
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 62
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 63
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 64
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 65
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 66
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 67
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 68
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 69
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 70
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 71
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 72
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 73
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 74
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 75
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 76
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 77
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 78
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 79
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 80
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 81
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 82
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 83
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 84
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 85
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 86
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 87
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 88
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 89
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 90
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 91
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 92
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 93
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 94
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 95
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 96
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 97
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 98
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 99
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 100
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
I/GridListAdapter(29826): 0
```

I use the ViewHolderPattern for in the getView Method..

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GridView is most likely getting re-measured for layout.  Every time it does this, it will obtain the 0th view as scrap.  A common reason this happens is when there is an ImageView in a GridView.  Updating the image will cause the layout to be recalculated.